# Не проходят ajax запросы в Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors, microsoft-edge

Есть веб-страница, которая делает ajax-запросы к API, расположенному на другом домене. В API выставлены заголовки `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`, и во всех браузерах, кроме Edge, даже в ИЕ, проблем с получением данных нет.

Edge блокирует все попытки сделать запрос, во вкладке сетевых запросов даже не отображается, что запрос происходит. В консоль падает ошибка

> Request has been terminated Possible causes: the network is offline, Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin, the page is being unloaded, etc."

Хотя в других браузерах видно, что заголовок на `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` приходит со *.

Пробовал и xmlhttprequest и fetch, ошибки разные - результат один - нулевой.

P.S. установил Fiddler и заметил странную зависимость, когда он включен запросы проходят нормально.